# Door trim coming off?

Tags: doors, exterior, trim

Hoping to get some insight, or light in this dark forest. I live in Vancouver Canada. This winter I noticed the exterior door by the garage was leaking. I believe it was leaking from the bottom-side door sill! So I caulked the sides of the door sill. Seems to be doing the job until yesterday. As I no longer see water marks on the inside bottom corners. Last week was an awesome weather so humidity was pretty low, just darn too sunny.

I found out that the interior side top door trim was pushing away from the wall. And I also found out that there was a gap between the exterior side top part of the door trim(photos).

Could it be just the moisture from the previous leak just drying up inside the wall causing this? Like Im hoping it is but seems odd that the wster would leak on from the door sill and months later when it dries all up the top of the door trim starts to shift.. What are your thoughts? Just caulk the gap? :)

Thanks guys,

[image]
[image]

Comment: So the trim is separating from the door on the inside AND the outside? Wood swells when wet, but this looks like it swelled quite a lot and then shrank when it dried. You may have mounting issues with the door jamb (if vibrates quite a bit when closed it would push trim on both sides of the door.
If you're totally sure the jamb is solid and the water issue is resolved, you can hammer the trim back in place (looks like it's stapled) and caulk it.

Comment: Water should never really reach that point. The white Z-flashing above it should keep it dry. I wonder if there's a problem higher up.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the jamb is pulling away from the jamb extension at the top of the door.

I don't think this is water related.  You have a decent overhang and you have a metal jamb flashing header.

If I had to guess I'd say your jamb wasn't secured at the top and someone kicked/bumped/rammed it and the jamb was pushed inside displacing the interior trim and detaching from the weakly attached jamb extension.

Comment: Thanks Fresh Codemonger. Your answer seems about right. After seeing your answer it does seem off, connecting the door sill water problem and the trims coming apart. It is most likely two different problem. 

If the door was push towards the inside it would have an exact result. The exterior trim would be away from the door as well as the interior trim away from the door/wall.